# Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>' to the project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I Created  an  asp.net core project And I selected UseIndiviualUserAccount As My AutenticationType,
After preparing project by visual studio i got some prebuilt class and controller,
Obviously i got migration folder and its config since i dont want to use defulat structure of asp.net core ,i deleted the migration folder and i created a new class library and i Rename it to MyProject.Core.
in MyProject.Core Class Library i create my db models and dbContext classes,so i need to run the add-migration "init" command for creating my database so i did but i got below error,
Note : i am running the add migration command in Myproject.Core in PMC !!
***Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'. Add an implementation of 'IDesignTimeDbContextFactory' to the project, or see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 for additional patterns supported at design time.***

how can i fix this error, i read some article in current site and the other website but i cant fix my problem.

[image: My project Structure]

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}


public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<IProvinceRepository, ProvinceRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IBrandRepository, BrandRepository>();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,ApplicationRole,string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        // Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide code from your Startup and ApplicationDbContext classes.

Comment: @brad yes,i do ...

Comment: What project are you trying to generate migrations in?

Comment: @Brad MyProject.Core

Comment: Your MyProject.Core project is a .NET Standard project.  You have to generate migrations from a .NET Core App project with a Startup class so your ApplicationDbContext can be created from the service provider.

Comment: @Brad 1.Im sure that project is .Net Core project 2.I did not understand the second part of your words always we have to put our dbcontext and migration folder in main project( we have no premission for  doing  this approch in a class library ?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171671/discussion-between-hamid-and-brad).

Answer (score 5):

This can happen when EF don't know where the entry point to your application is. You **do not** need to implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` if you're using `BuildWebHost`.
First of all, make sure that you are running your migration from the project containing the migrations.

Eg... if you're using `Package Manager Console`:

```
cd .\MyProject.Core
```

Then run your migration using [`startup-project`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#using-the-tools) and point it to the project with `BuildWebHost`.

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../MyProject.Web/ migrations add Initial
```

Otherwise EF will not know where your implementation is.

Comment: Just to add to this post to help others that are like myself, if you are trying to run migrations on a Mac, and are doing so from the terminal, you will need to specify the startup project from the terminal as well exactly like described in this post.

Comment: This helped me get three things right:
1) set to web-project as startup-project in solution (or add it to command line with parameter as shown);
2) change directory in Package Manager Console to data-project;
3) change "default project" (drop down on top) in Package Manager Console to data-project.